# Data from twilio

Tags: javascript, node.js, sms, twilio-twiml

> ```
> client.messages
>     .list({
>         from: '123456786',
>         limit: 1
>         })
>     .then(messages => messages.forEach(m => console.log(odp = m.body)));
> ```

I tried:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {client.messages
        .list({
            from: '123456789',
            limit: 1
            })
        .then(messages => messages.forEach(m => m.body)); 
    });
  }
  
  async function asyncCall() {
    const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
    console.log(result)
  }
  asyncCall();
```

I use with Twilio.
I have such a code. Thanks to this, the last message from the given number is displayed in the console.
I'd like to assign the result to a variable so I can use "if" to perform an action later.

Unfortunately, it is not caught. I am a novice on this subject. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that the Promise doesn't return a value with resolve. The correct code would look like this:

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    client.messages
    .list({
      from: NUMBER,
      limit: 1
    })
    .then(messages => resolve(messages[0].body));
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result)
}
asyncCall();
```

I noticed that the function name is `resolveAfter2Seconds`, but no timeout is included. If you don't need this time delay, you could also use `await` with the client method and don't need to build your own Promise.

```js
const messages = await client.messages
    .list({
      from: NUMBER,
      limit: 1
    });
console.log(messages[0].body)
```